# Select padding issue when overlaying a div with a form over a div with background color

Tags: html, css, overlay, padding

I am trying to overlay a div that has a reservation form in it over a div that has a background color using position technique. When I added padding to div has background color, the `<select>` affected by padding of div.

Code I have is:

http://codepen.io/thehung1724/full/bptxj/

**HTML**

```
<div id="reservation">
  <div class="container">                               
    <form action="#" class="reservation-section">
      <div class="reservation-form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="room">Type of room:</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="room" id="room">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a type of room</option>
                <option value="Single">Single room</option>
                <option value="Double">Double room</option>
                <option value="Deluxe">Deluxe room</option>
              </select>
            </div>  <!-- end form-group -->
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="checkin">Check-in date:</label>
              <i class="fa fa-calendar infield"></i>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="checkin" name="checkin" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
            </div>  <!-- end form-group -->
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="checkout">Check-in date:</label>
              <i class="fa fa-calendar infield"></i>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="checkout" name="checkout" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
            </div>  <!-- end form-group -->
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="room">Adults:</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="room" id="room">
                <option value="one">1</option>
                <option value="two">2</option>
                <option value="three">3</option>
              </select>
            </div>  <!-- end form-group -->
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="room">Children:</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="room" id="room">
                <option value="one">1</option>
                <option value="two">2</option>
                <option value="three">3</option>
              </select>
            </div>  <!-- end form-group -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    <!-- end reservation-form -->
    </form> <!-- end reservation-section -->
  </div>    <!-- end container -->
</div>  <!-- end reservation -->

<div id="room">
  Simple test goes here
</div>  <!-- end room -->
```

**CSS (LESS)**

```
body{
  margin-top: 150px;
}

/* 5. RESERVATION */
#reservation{
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.reservation-section{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: -50px;

    .form-group{
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 100%;

        .form-control{
            color: #373535;
            border: 1px solid #d6d4d4;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        label{
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }
}

/* 6. RESERVATION */
#room{
  padding-top: 90px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to design but your select elements have same id(#room) and the div with background color, so css

```
#room{
  padding-top: 90px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

applies to them too. 
You should not have same ids in same page, anyway